# fo-dicom, Get DicomTag RegionLocationMinX0 and PhysicalDeltaX

Tags: c#, fo-dicom

I used the following to retrieve the values of some dicom tags using fo-dicom:

ulong imageMin_x = file.Dataset.Get< ulong >(DicomTag.RegionLocationMinX0);

double delta_x = file.Dataset.Get< double >(DicomTag.PhysicalDeltaX);

The values are both 0. When I used Matlab dicominfo() to show the tags, however they have non-zero values. How can I make the retrieval happen in C# using fo-dicom?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. It is region sequence based. Hope it helps.

```
        DicomSequence ds = file.Dataset.Get<DicomSequence>(DicomTag.SequenceOfUltrasoundRegions);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Items.Count; ++i)
        {
            DicomDataset dds = ds.Items[i];
            imageMin_x = dds.Get<ulong>(DicomTag.RegionLocationMinX0);
            imageMin_y = dds.Get<ulong>(DicomTag.RegionLocationMinY0);
            imageMax_x = dds.Get<ulong>(DicomTag.RegionLocationMaxX1);
            imageMax_y = dds.Get<ulong>(DicomTag.RegionLocationMaxY1);

            delta_x = dds.Get<double>(DicomTag.PhysicalDeltaX);
            delta_y = dds.Get<double>(DicomTag.PhysicalDeltaY);
        }
```